# Import large number of lines from MsAccess in .net fast.

Tags: .net, ms-access

I need to import a large number of lines from a table in MsAccess, that match primary keys that I have in memory in my .net program. Unfortunately, there is no way to determine these keys on the DB side. So I need to somehow send requests to MsAccess to obtain the lines with the matching primary key.

What is the fastest reliable approach to obtain this data?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to perform database operation from your .NET side.
2. To do that you need to connect to your access database from your .NET side.
3. To do that, you need a valid driver + connection string in situ.
4. using System.Data.OleDb;
5. Access ACE/JET driver is installed

.Net side you would be doing something like:

```
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};", _local_dbname);
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable where key = from your variable/memory", connection);
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("reading row: "  + reader["ID"].ToString());                   
    }
    reader.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // your exception

}
```

more here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=connecting+to+ms+access+database+.c%23

try this and post your code when you are stuck.

Comment: This works, but it is not very fast:I need to obtain thousands of rows in this fashion. Can I do anything about the speed?